# No 'Add New item' button in mobile view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365, 2016

I have created a publishing site in SharePoint 2016 with one document library, In the mobile view i can see the documents which are already uploaded . But i dont get the 'Add New' item to upload from my phone . I tried with the farm account and all other accounts with 'Contribute' permissions , but still no success .Is there any configuration needed ?